# What do astronauts do with their trash on the ISS?

Tags: iss, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, astronauts

Astronauts often stay more than a year on the ISS, they produce trash like any other human. Is there like a limit that they may produce ever day or maybe some measures were put in place to reduce the amount of trash produced every day?

Comment: It is very expensive to transport material to the ISS. So the funds for transport limit the amount of trash.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The obvious natural limit on amount of trash comes from the law of preservation of mass: they can't make more trash than the amount of material that was delivered by a delivery spacecraft with a resupply mission. They pack all the trash into bags kept for that specific purpose, and when a cargo spacecraft is to undock to be deorbited and burn up in the atmosphere or land, it's loaded with all the accumulated trash, which then subsequently burns up in the atmosphere with the spacecraft or splashes down on Earth. (and obviously since it all fit on the way up, it fits on the way down.)

Comment: Have there ever been any incidents where something (especially anything valuable)  was unintentionally put into the spacecraft-turned-incinerator by mistake?

Comment: @Dai that could make a nice question in itself.

Comment: @Dai interesting question - you should ask it as a new question. I'd be interested to hear the answer

Comment: Just because it fit on the way up doesn't mean it will fit on the way down, because trash may not pack as densely as the incoming cargo was packed. Unless they have a compactor up there?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: They don't, they pack these bags manually quite tightly though (they have a drawstring which you can use to squeeze the contents before tying the bag off). Besides supplies, the cargo spacecraft delivers some satellites (cubesats), experimental equipment that remains on the station, and water that gets electrolyzed and then vented with CO2 or methane byproduct (which also contains carbon that is the building block of the food). In short the craft usually leaves more empty than it arrives. Also, for old broken station hardware, Russians tend to lob it in retrograde direction.

Comment: This might be worthy of another question, but ... is human solid waste treated the same as trash in this regard?  Stored in containers and then placed in earthward bound vehicles?

Comment: @Moo: Yes, it's worthy. I know it is deorbited with the rest of the trash but I don't know what sort of processing (if any) it undergoes between being packaged in small plastic bags after use of the space potty and turning into hot plasma in the stratosphere.