# Have there ever been any incidents where something valuable was unintentionally thrown out with the trash?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight

In "[What do astronauts do with their trash on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36153/what-do-astronauts-do-with-their-trash-on-the-iss)", a commentator asked the title question and was encouraged to make it a new question, but apparently never did.

The linked question is referring to things that were on-board and inside the ISS for use by the crew (and disposed of as part of the crew's normal garbage disposal procedure), so the same parameters apply here.

If so, what, when, and how much?

Comment: Great question- though I suspect incidents we DO know of could potentially suffer from survivors bias. Do fuel bodies and lower rocket stages count? Those are pretty expensive when disposed of ;). Or just ISS waste?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Just ISS waste; I added a clarifying statement. :)

Comment: I'm half expecting someone to answer that something of sentimental value was lost in addition to things that are expensive too. But that could be just as interesting! +1

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Accidentally tossing your wedding ring into the ISS garbage is orders of magnitude worse than losing it in the sink. :)

Comment: It may be hard to tell.  There was a long-running problem with losing track of where various things on ISS were stored, especially once they were packed and re-packed.  See e.g. https://www.airspacemag.com/space/lost-in-space-2217739/  I'm not sure if anyone in the agency would take the position that an item had gotten into the trash instead of just been lost...but I hope I'm wrong :)

Comment: [This document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110022528.pdf) seems to suggest that each individual item of trash is logged and tracked on a spreadsheet before it's finally designated for disposal. It feels like there's very little scope for an item to be ditched by accident if you're checking and re-checking each thing that goes into the bin.

Comment: @Richard at this point I would consider that an answer...

Comment: I asked Paul Dye, the longest-serving NASA flight director and apparently there were a few instances of things brought back from Mir that should have stayed on the station. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/humooh/im_paul_dye_the_longestserving_nasa_flight/fyofv8c/

Comment: No. While there is no place that says that nothing valuable was ever thrown out in the trash on the ISS, there also is no place that says that that has happened.

Comment: @Richard In the western segment, maybe. Watching a lengthy documentary and a number of videos made privately by cosmonauts, seems like their meal procedure is "take whichever meal you fancy for the day, prepare a small trash bag (with a draw-string), while eating the meal dispose of the emptied packages into the trash bag, then compress (squeeze) the trash bag tightly and tie it over to keep it minimized, then add it to the large garbage bag." - there's no logging of anything. I'd be quite unsurprised if Russians lost something in their trash.

Comment: I remember several years ago in ISS crews' task sheets on NASA site one task was appearing for a long time (several weeks). Russian crew was searching for some lost item. I don't know did they find it finally or not.